# How to scp folders with nasty names using a shell function

Tags: zsh, quoting, scp

I am trying to write a function that I will put on all my machines in order to make it easy to send files at a fixed place on my network.

Here is my script so far. Some folder may have duplicates names on my machines, so I'm adding a uuid at the end of the folder name.

```
function putOnSG3() {
uuid=`uuidgen`
if [[ -d $1 ]]; then scp -rv "$1" shiny:/Volumes/Seagate3To/"$1.$uuid";
else echo $1 " is not a directory. Not copying.";
fi;
}
```

I'm invoking it like this:

```
$ putOnSG testFo\[l\}der
```

Here is the problem:

```
zsh:1: bad pattern: /Volumes/Seagate3To/testFo[l}der.d84abc26-501b-4f89-a636-518b4059a770
```

How can I manage these nasty filenames ?

Target filesystem is case sensitive hfsplus, source filesystems are various extfs from Linux machines and NTFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
function putOnSG() {
uuid=`uuidgen`
if [[ -d $1 ]]; then du -sh "$1";
scp -rv "$1" shiny:/Volumes/Seagate3To/\"$1\".$uuid
else echo $1 "is not a directory. Not copying.";
fi;
}
```

The only differences with my initial non working solution are the backslashes around the quotes in the second argument of scp.

Comment: You've stumbled on the correct solution.  The special consideration with `scp` arguments is they have to be "double-quoted".  This is because an `scp` argument, like any normal shell argument, is interpreted by your shell.  However, once `scp` gets the argument, it has to pass it to a remote shell on the other machine, and the shell there interprets it once again.  That is why two layers of quoting are required (``\`` and `"`).

Comment: I asked a question specifically about scp and quotes: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58499/escaping-quotes-for-scp if you want to elaborate on the subject of double-quoting which is still not very clear for me.

Comment: What part is unclear?  I'm not sure I could explain it any better than what I said in the above comment.  Maybe someone else can explain it better.

Comment: The part where you say that the remote shell interprets the argument once again. Any example involving `uname` ?

Comment: The idea is any argument to scp goes through two shells - first the local one and then remote one.  Since shells strip quotes, if you need the remote shell to see quotes, you'll need to quote them so the local shell doesn't remove them.  Not sure how `uname` is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

All special symbols, like [,],(,),#, etc you should write after backslash "\". You can try do it:

```
$ touch test\[ ; ll test\[ ;
-rw-r--r-- 1 s.gvozdetskiy s.gvozdetskiy 0 Dec 12 12:00 test[
$ mkdir test\[ ; ll ./
...
drwxr-xr-x 2 s.gvozdetskiy s.gvozdetskiy     4096 Dec 12 12:04 test[
...
```

I think hfsplus support there specific.

Comment: The problem occurs when scp receives the already quoted argument. The shell already takes care of the quoting (with tab completion for example) in the case I test the function manually.

Comment: So what's problem? Copy successful:
`scp -rv test\[/ s.gvozdetskiy@foo-server:/home/s.gvozdetskiy
s.gvozdetskiy@172.16.1.252's password:`

`[s.gvozdetskiy@foo-server ~]$ ll
...
drwxr-xr-x 2 s.gvozdetskiy s.gvozdetskiy      4096 Dec 12 12:41 test[
...`
Or youre problem in function?

Comment: Is your scp inside a function?

Comment: No, from console and no problem. I modify your script and copy successfull too:
`$ cat put.sh
#!/bin/sh

function putOnSG3() {
        uuid=`uuidgen`
        if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
                scp -i /s.gvozdetskiy/.ssh/id_rsa -rv "$1" s.gvozdetskiy@foo-server:/home/s.gvozdetskiy/"$1.$uuid" &2>1;
        else echo $1 " is not a directory. Not copying.";
fi
}
putOnSG3 test\[`

I used ssh-keys for authorize on foo-server.