# Escaping quotes for scp

Tags: zsh, quoting, scp

I needed to write a that behaves correctly with nasty (spaces, braces, etc..) 
filenames.

```
scp -rv "$1" shiny:/Volumes/Seagate3To/\"$1\"
```

This function works, but I don't understand why the quotes need escaping in the second argument of `scp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let say $1 is

```
This is a test directory name
```

We escape the double quote because we want to pass the target directory (part after colon) as a whole (including the double quotes) to the target machine.

Following is what we want to past to target

```
/Volumes/Seagate3To/"This is a test directory name"
```

Without the escape, the double quote will be consumed by the local machine and following string is sent, which become 6 strings separated by space

```
/Volumes/Seagate3To/This is a test directory name
```

Resulting an error.